# How to make the nav bar responsive with custom css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Here I trying to create a website with bootstrap. The website remains responsive untill I change the text size and gab of nav item. Bootstrap navbar default size is little small as i try to use `fs-4` and `style="gap: 10vh;"` to increase the size and gap. when I do that website no longer remain responsive  for lower screens.

```
<body>
    <header class="header">

        <nav class="p-nav navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light border " >
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto mb-0 mb-lg-0 d-flex justify-content-between " style="gap: 10vh;" >
                        <li class="nav-item fs-4">
                            <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="#" >Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item fs-4">
                            <a class="nav-link " href="#" >Service</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item fs-4">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Service Area</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item fs-4">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Fleet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item fs-4">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Reservation</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item fs-4">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Faq</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item fs-4">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <img src="assets/car(container).gif" alt="" class="img-fluid img-cc">


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

[here is before changing the size and gab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjjtX.png)

[and here is after i added gab and increase size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCzNY.png)
[without gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1LuQ.jpg)

I try to apply custom css other bootstrap untilities but the it is still not responsive.

Comment: You should not be messing with the `gap` here. The UL already has the class `justify-content-between`, so making the UL take the full container with, by giving it `width: 100%`, would probably make a lot more sense.

Comment: Sorry for asking but gab==gap?

Comment: look. I am trying to create website according to my taste and requirement. here I am will decide what should I and what I shouldn't. without gap website looks like something else which I have updated in question. yes it's gap. my mitake

Comment: @Crystal you can use media queries for custom font size so you can set different different font size for your nav bar and it wont break the site and will remain responsive. Please read about media query on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to solve your layout doing the minimum change, is styling your `ul.navbar-nav` with `flex-grow: 1`.

The reason is because you have multiple flex containers wrapping each other and you need here the list to take the whole available width while still being a flex item in its parent container.

You tried to add `gap` but it actually made the ul content overflow the available width. While since the navbar is a flex container, you wish the ul to just take the whole available width without overflowing and yet automatically keep even space around its children items (given by `justify-content-between` that translates to `justify-content: space-between`).

At first I added the css property set as an inline style in place of your `gap`... but it would be equivalent to adding the bootstrap class `flex-grow-1` to the element.

As per the font size of your `li` items, you used the bootstrap `fs-4` class that by default translates to `font-size: calc(1.275rem + .3vw)!important;`.

Since it's not clear what are your requirements about it, and since there are several ways to make it shrink down according to the screen size like using media queries or using relative units, in this case a first approach could be just use a custom size expressed in `vw` units.

So in this case I used `font-size: 2.5vw !important;` in a css rule added to address those items. That way the size will be smaller with smaller screen and bigger in bigger screen but you won't have thresholds like you would with media queries. I need you to be more exact if you need a different behaviour.

```css
ul.navbar-nav > li{
  font-size: 2.5vw !important; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <header class="header">

    <nav class="p-nav navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light border ">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation">        
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        
          <!-- added class flex-grow-1 -->
          <ul
            class="flex-grow-1 navbar-nav m-auto mb-0 mb-lg-0 d-flex justify-content-between ">    
            <!-- removed class fs-4 and style ul > li items via css rule -->
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Service</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Service Area</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item fs-4">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Fleet</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reservation</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Faq</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <img src="assets/car(container).gif" alt="" class="img-fluid img-cc">

</body>
```

Comment: It is still not responsive the problem is same due to increase in size. the text size isn't shirking with the screen

Comment: to me responsive means the layout... I was focused on that problem since you talked about adding a gap between the list items. I may try to address also the font size

Comment: I added the part relative to the font size but I couldn't address the issue better than that given the conditions. The picture you shared showing the situation before adding the `gap` is actually not telling how the font size was set. Or maybe you need to tell how small you want it relative to the screen width thresholds

Comment: ?. first  image show how the web look when using purly bootstrap strap and in it's default size. Second images show what happens when i add class `fs-4`  which is bootstrap utility class to increase the text size in which  text starts to overlap on shirking the screen

Comment: ok by the way I'm still waiting your feedback about the latest updates to my answer. You can see the font size is relative to the screen size.. always... so the smaller the screen size the smaller is the font size

Comment: yep. it working as i intended to. i just decrease the custome size to 1.5. thx